# GCE SSD persistent disk slower than Standard persistent disk

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

We are using GCE for a MongoDB replica set with three members. As our data is quite large the initial sync for a new member is taking quite a lot. In our case the initial sync takes 7 hours for copying records and then 30 hours to create indexes.

The database is stored on a separate disk with these properties (copy-paste from the GCE console):

```
Type: Standard persistent disk
Size: 2000 GB
Zone: us-central1-c
Sustained random IOPS limit - estimated (R/W): 1,500 / 3,000
Sustained throughput limit (MB/s) - estimated (R/W): 180 / 120
```

To speed up we tried to add an SSD disk:

```
Type: SSD persistent disk
Size: 1000 GB
Zone: us-central1-c
Sustained random IOPS limit - estimated (R/W): 15,000 / 15,000
Sustained throughput limit (MB/s) - estimated: 240 / 240
```

One would expect that SSD disk should be quite faster than a Standard disk. But our results are different. During the initial MongoDB sync Standard disk was several time faster than the SSD. While it took 7 hours for the Standard disk to copy all data, the SSD disk after 12 hours had copied just half of data. We used Linux tool iostat and measured, Standard disk is achieving around 80,000 kB_wrtn/s while the SSD disk is around 8,000 kB_wrtn/s. How is possible that SSD disks is 10 times slower than the Standard disk?

Comment: That's odd. Couple questions, what kind of IOPS are you seeing? And, how big is the instance being used (and what OS is it?)

Comment: @PaulR.Nash as this is initial MongoDB synchronisation we are just seeing "writes". The instance is 2 vCPUs with 11.25 GB memory in us-central1-c  with latest stable Debian. No other services are running on the server. Just the MongoDB.

Comment: I've never suffered so much using a cloud. Google Cloud ... zzzzz

Comment: Users should be aware that disk performance is a function of the disk type, size, and number of vCPUs. This article may be of some use to those with similar issues. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance#size_price_performance